# Adding images into source code

Tags: java, image, comments

Is there a way (or an editor) that allows me to link an image/files/http links from within a source file (*.java for instance), sort of like a rich text document?

This way, while reading the code I can quickly look at the appended image (augmenting the comments), instead of opening the browser etc.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151744/do-you-use-ascii-art-to-decorate-your-code

Comment: if you can do it (e.g by hacking javadoc to take raw image html), it's probably a bad idea - what happens if the remote resource becomes no longer available for some reason?

Comment: If I use eclipse, then maybe there is something that the eclipse plugin can do? 

@Richard Well, the image will just sit right along the code in the same directory.

@polygenelubricants, thanks for the links, I can always convert my image into an ascii art.

Comment: apparently no hacking of javadoc required, can embed image no problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Javadocs are HTML, so you can just embed images there:

```
/**
 * This class does some funky stuff (see diagram).
 * <img src="relative/path/to/your/image.png" />
 * 
 */
 public class FunkyClass{
 }
```

Eclipse will happily show you the images in the javadoc view or on hovering over the comment. Other IDEs might or might not do the same.

Obviously you have to make sure somehow that the images are deployed with the javadocs...

Answer (score 4):

You can add `<img src="">` and `<a href="">` in the javadoc of your classes.

You probably have tools and plug-ins that allow easily to see the Javadoc of your file.

One good example of mixing images and links in Javadoc is [JRootPane](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html)

Comment: good example, but awful art. these curly braces are from hell :-)

Comment: Are you kidding me? I can not believe my eyes. Ironically, this is in the GUI part of the docu... +1 for showing me this masterpiece of fine art.

Answer (score 1):

As many says you can use  but for example in Eclipse you encouter error if you don't declare "alt" and if you use "selfclosing" tag like

```
<img alt="image desc" src="path/img.jpg">
```

seems not givin error =)

Comment: I tried `<img src="path/img.jpg">` and it worked for me,without `alt`.

Comment: Well, maybe could be the version of Eclipse(kepler for me) that don't accept missing alt but use alt is more for SEO xP

Answer (score -1):

By industry standard, source code is almost always text-only (be it encoded in ASCII or unicode). You can always draw an ASCII art. ;-)

Comment: Not necessarily. Microsoft code style documentation standards allow for a links to types etc in documentation.

Comment: ok, so does java, of course. but those links are implemented in ascii through javadoc tags