# Images as a part of source code documentation / comments?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, documentation

My question is similar to [Adding images into source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903042/adding-images-into-source-code), but my environment is Visual C++. Is there some way how to add images as a part of comments and make the IDE to display them (either inline, or by clicking on them or performing some action on them)?

What I was doing until now was either to provide an URL to an external .PNG or .SVG file placed in the SVN using its URL, or by creating an ASCII art, but it somehow feels strange to me in the age of GUIs and rich documents everywhere be still limited to this. If there is no better solution, are there at least some pluings to make this more streamlined (e.g. by creating the SVN document for me and placing a link to it in the comment, or by helping me in the ASCII art drawing)?

Comment: I don't know about visual studio, but I wouldn't have thought so as code files are just plain text files.  Personally I would hate having to read code with rich text formatting, the images would probably my layout by interfering with syntax highlighting, font size, etc.

Comment: IMO, it would be great if I could reference images by URI, and that the editor would show them when I hover over the link. That would not be as intruisive as rendering them inline in source.

Comment: And why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Embedding a drawing within comments would be useful for state diagrams.  Having them within the source code would avoid forgetting to maintain an external file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample add in that appears to be doing this. I haven't run it.

[Here's the link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/793d16d0-235a-439a-91df-4ce7c721df12/). Source code is available.

Comment: I have tried the add-in, but it does not work for me (showing Visual Studio exception message box once drop is about to be initiated). Either it does not support native C++ sources, or it is unreliable.