# Link local image in javadoc using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

Is there a way to include an image in the class javadoc that is local in an Android project using Android Studio?

I would like to add a diagram to clarify the workings of a class.
My structure is as follows:

```
src/main/com.exampe.project/Class.java
docs/images/Diagram.png
```

Now I would like to add javadoc to the class, linking to `Diagram.png`.

My code now looks something like this:

```
/**
 * <img src="docs/images/Diagram.png">
 */
public class Class {
```

However, the javadoc linking does not work. Is there any way to show the image in the javadoc?

**Update:**

Apparently, you can use the docroot attribute, but this does not work for the current version of Android Studio. When I change the javadoc to

```
/**
 * <a href="{@docRoot}docs/images/Diagram.png">link</a>
 */
public class Class {
```

and click on the link, it can not find the file, because it points to `/Applications/Android Studio.app/bin/../../../../docs/images/Diagram.png`. It appears Android Studio searches for the image in the install directory of the program, instead of the root of the project. (this is on a mac)

Comment: This should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903042/adding-images-into-source-code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images in Javadoc with IntelliJ Idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382586/images-in-javadoc-with-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1):

with comment as:

```
/**
 * <img src="../../../images/Diagram.png"/>
 */
```

In the case of source with `CLASSPATH=src/main/` and code in:
`src/main/com/exampe/project/Class.java`
(java class after 3 directories)

and Java documentation in `doc/`
`docs/images/Diagram.png`

Then the output of java doc is here:
`docs/com/example/project/Class.html`