# Images in JavaDoc with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm trying to include images in my JavaDoc. I follow [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#images) and store an image in the `doc-files` in the package directory. My javadoc looks like:

```
/**
 * This is class desctiprion. Image:
 * <p><img src="doc-files/image.png"/></p>
 */
```

When I generate Javadoc the image is shown but when I try to review Javadoc in the Idea it shows just image stub. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the built-in JavaDoc viewer doesn't do what you want.

There are a few other possibilities, though:

- I haven't tried it, but there's a JavaDoc viewer plugin at http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/612 - give it a try, and see if it meets your needs.
- Perhaps you could write a plugin using jetbrains' api?
- Put in a feature request.

Comment: Plugin in question doesn't work for Intellij 15 per comment on linked page.